# Посчитать кол-во записей в таблице для каждого уникального значения столбца

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пусть есть таблица с транзакциями
(`клиент_отправитель, клиент_получатель, сумма, дата` ,etc. )
таблица приведена для примера и не имеет отношения к реальной задаче.

Проблема - сделать вывод таблицы, где для каждого уникального `клиент_отправитель` будет стоять кол-во транзакций за определённую дату(период).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну обычный же вроде `SQL` запрос, примерно такой, хотя в деталях могу ошибаться:

```
select клиент_отправитель, count(*)
from таблица
where дата between начало and конец
group by клиент_отправитель
```

Comment: да, чего-то я не подумал про group by, начал join саму на себя городить, что-то обвязывать сложное. Спасибо большое